# Can AWS RDS Proxy be paired with read replication instance directly?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

I created an **RDS Proxy** with existing Aurora PostgreSQL **cluster**.

But I want to pair the proxy with specific **read replica instance** of the cluster. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what AWS claims about RDS proxy:

> The same consideration applies for RDS DB instances in replication configurations. You can associate a proxy only with the writer DB instance, not a read replica.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html

Comment: As of March 2021 this is supported - Please check https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/amazon-rds-proxy-adds-read-only-endpoints-for-amazon-aurora-replicas/#:~:text=Amazon%20RDS%20Proxy%20now%20lets,connected%20through%20the%20RDS%20Proxy.

Comment: @AmeenIbrahimRaffic-'AIR' Its supported only in Amazon Aurora Replicas, Not supported in MySQL replicas yet.

Comment: I was not able to connect to the RDS replica.  You can create a read only endpoint but it is my understanding that it is still uses the writer instance.  I submitted a question to AWS to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible now as per https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/amazon-rds-proxy-adds-read-only-endpoints-for-amazon-aurora-replicas/

Answer (score 0):

Try RDS Proxy Endpoint, which allows you to get use of read replicas:

> You can create and connect to read-only endpoints called reader endpoints when you use RDS Proxy with Aurora clusters. These reader endpoints help to improve the read scalability of your query-intensive applications. Reader endpoints also help to improve the availability of your connections if a reader DB instance in your cluster becomes unavailable.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy-endpoints